# GrowlNotify 1.3 + Growl 1.3.1 for Lion: error

Tags: growl, growlnotify

I'm working on Mac OS X 10.7.2 with Growl 1.3.1 for Lion. I installed 
growlnotify version 1.3 and executed `growlnotify -a Emacs.app -m "foo"` 
in the terminal. I obtain:

```
2011-12-11 11:26:39.349 growlnotify[86152:707] <GrowlGNTPRegistrationAttempt: 0x7fa202017f00> failed because Error Domain=GCDAsyncSocketErrorDomain Code=7 "Socket closed by remote peer" UserInfo=0x7fa202202450 {NSLocalizedDescription=Socket closed by remote peer}
2011-12-11 11:26:39.351 growlnotify[86152:707] Failed to register with (null)
```

Afterwards, growl disappears from the menu bar. In other words: It crashed.

Has anyone experienced something similar?

It's most likely not an emacs problem, I also get this if I choose other applications.

Comment: I just updated Growl to 1.3.2 and the problem disappeared completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting a password in your Growl network settings and specify the password via the -P option.

Apparently it's a known bug: http://metacpan.org/pod/Net::Growl#Internal-OO-API-only

Answer (score 6):

I know this **may not apply specifically to OS X 10.7.2** but I came to this answer looking for a way to Growel in the latest (currently Yosemite 10.10.5) and found [this other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115373/40724) that works in Mavericks+ and was exactly what I was looking for:

> With Mavericks and later, you can do this using AppleScript's 'display notification':
>
> `display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"`
>
> AppleScript can be run from the shell using /usr/bin/osascript:
>
> `osascript -e 'display notification "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" with title "Title"'`

There are a lot more details in [How can I trigger a Notification Center notification from an AppleScript or shell script?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/115373/40724)